# Executar loadScreen enquanto imagem não carrega

Tags: javascript, jquery

Na minha galeria, quando o usuário clica em proximo ou anterior, o código abaixo é executado:

```
function galeria(BASE_URL, nGaleria) {
  $('.splash-load').removeClass('hide');

  var conteudo = "<img id='imagemCarousel"+numeroImagem+"' class='d-block w-100' src='" + BASE_URL + "assets/img/galeria/1-encontro-regional-de-educacao (" + numeroImagem + ").jpg'>";
  var id = $('.carousel-item.active').attr('id');
  var nomeClasse = ".carousel-" + numeroImagem;
  var imagemCarregada = "#imagemCarousel"+numeroImagem;

  if (!$(nomeClasse).length) {
    $('.carousel-item.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.carousel-inner').append(conteudo);
  } else {
    $('.carousel-item.active').removeClass('active');
    $(nomeClasse).addClass('active');
  }
  $('.splash-load').addClass('hide');
}
```

`$('.splash-load').removeClass('hide');` é a div de load que deve aparecer quando a imagem está sendo carregado.

O problema que estou tendo, é que mesmo que eu faça a div aparecer no começo da função e remova no final, quando a execução da função acaba a a imagem ainda não foi carregada... dessa forma na verdade você não consegue nem mesmo ver o load aparecendo.

O que eu preciso saber é como eu vejo se essa imagem já foi carregada dentro da função.

Obrigado!

Comment: Eu estava com um problema parecido resolvi desta maneira usando "addEventListener" Segue exemplo:
https://jsfiddle.net/Clopes_XD/L215xnbk/ espero ter ajudado